# I need to make a program that takes the median of a list of numbers then finds the middle number

Tags: python, function, subscript

I have a problem that one of the things i need to include is a subscript of median, but i have no clue what that means

I have tried most things but again i have no clue what subscript of median means.

```
def median(a):
    a=a.sort()
    a=len(a)/2
    return a

def main():
    print(median([3,1,2]))
    print(median([4,3,2,1]))
    print(median([1,5,3,2,4]))
    print(median([6,5,1,2,3,4]))

main()
```

I expect it to print out the median of the numbers if it gets two i need the lesser... We cant use average.

Comment: What makes you think you need to include "a subscript of median" if you don't know what that means?

Comment: it was ask buy the professor to include in the problem

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the middle index, not the value of the element at that index.

Also, `a.sort()` modifies the list in place, it doesn't return the sorted list; `a = a.sort()` sorts the list and then sets `a` to `None`.

```
def median(a):
    s = sorted(a)
    middle = int(len(s)/2)
    return s[middle]
```